# Deja Dup asking for password multiple times Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm hoping this is an easy answer: I'm running Deja Dup (or just 'Backup' in Ubuntu) to try to back my laptop onto an external drive.

It asks me to set a password when I start. I do, and then it starts scanning the hard drive to prepare for the backup. When it reaches the end of the files, it asks for my password again, and then starts scanning through the hard drive again.

I'm assuming it's not rejecting my password because it's proceeding with the whole scan, but it's asked for that password about 4 times now through, scanning the whole machine each time.

Do I just need to be patient, or is this caught in a loop and my backup will never get past the scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed and reinstalled Deja Dup via Synaptic.

I also re-named my backup(1) at which point it set me to a new prompt for creating a new password. It completed the scan and is backing up as we speak.

(1)What I didn't mention before is that I did have another backup on the same external drive, and I think Deja Dup was trying to write to that backup. So either removing and reinstalling the program reset the password problem, **or** choosing a different backup title allowed Deja Dup to start a new backup with a new password.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck in this loop and was able to get it working again by adding a new folder and setting that as the backup destination. Still feels like a workaround, but I'll take it for now